# How to change rectangle color in xml layout

Tags: android

My current approach:

I create Rectangle in separate file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
     <solid>@color/red</solid>
</shape>
```

And later I reference it in my layout like this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/rectimage"
    android:layout_width="17dp"
    android:layout_height="17dp"
    android:src="@drawable/rectangle">
</ImageView>
```

How to change the color in xml layout? I'd like to have different color for each rectangle, but I don't want to create separate drawable files for each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is very simple.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/rectimage"
    android:layout_width="17dp"
    android:layout_height="17dp"
    android:src="@drawable/rectangle">
    android:background="@color/blue"
</ImageView>
```

All is needed is to set background color. My failure was to set unsupported in 2.3 colors, so the rectangles were black.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the value of drawable xmls. All you can do is to create the rectangles using [ShapeDrawables](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable.html).